# What is different about the way NodeJS handles requests as opposed to a setup like Rails / Passenger?

Tags: node.js

My understanding is that Node is an 'Event' driven as opposed to sequentially driven server application.  This I've come to understand means, that for event driven software, the user is in command, he can create an event at any time and the server is in a state such that it can respond, whereas with sequential software (like a DOS prompt), the application tells the user when its 'ok' to response, and may at any given time be not available (due to some other process).

Further, my understanding is that applications like Node and EventMachine use a reactor of sorts.. they wait for an 'event' to occur, and using a callback they delegate the task to some other worker.  Ok.. so then, what about Rails & Passenger?

Rails might use a server like NGINX with Passenger to spawn new processes when 'events' are received by the system.  Is this not conceptually the same idea?  If it is, is it just the processing overhead that is really separating the two where Passenger would need to potentially spawn a new rails instance while, node is already waiting to handle the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is event driven non blocking programming language. The key is the non blocking part. Node doesn't spawn for other processes. It runs in one thread (this is for starters... you can actually spawn it now through some modules - i think - but that's another talk)

Anyway this is different from other typical programming languages where you receive a request and the thread is locked until it has an answer. If you assign it to another thread, that thread is still locked...

In node you never lock. You receive request and the thread continues to receive requests. When a request is processed, the callback is called.

Hope I made myself understand and I used the right terms ;)

Anyway, if you want this video is nicee: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I

Answer (score 0):

The non-blocking/evented I/O as jribeiro described is one part of the answer. Ruby applications tend to be written using blocking I/O, and using processes and threads for concurrency.

However, non-blocking and evented I/O are not inherent to Node. You can achieve the same thing in Ruby by using EventMachine, and an in-process evented server like Thin. If you program directly against EventMachine and Thin, then it is architecturally almost the same as Node. That being said, the Ruby ecosystem does not have as many event-friendly libraries and documentation as Node does, so it takes a bit of skill to achieve the same thing in Ruby.

Conversely, the way Phusion Passenger manages processes - i.e. by spawning multiple processes and load balancing requests between them, and supervising processes - is not unique to Ruby. In fact, Phusion Passenger introduced Node.js support recently. The Node.js support [was open sourced today](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/10/23/phusion-passengers-node-js-support-has-been-open-sourced/).